# How can we add local storage entries to the shopware cookie consent?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

We have an app which stores some information in the browser's local storage via javascript. The app was rejected in the review phase because it saved these entries without adding them to the cookie consent. From what I can see we can only add cookies to the cookie consent via the app's manifest. How could we add these local storage entries to the consent? We can add them as cookies in the manifest with the same names but that would create these as cookies once the consent is approved, which is not ideal and unnecessary. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could try to [override](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/override-existing-javascript?category=shopware-platform-dev-en/how-to) the [`CookieConfiguration`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/efcfd43896f1b2aa1480f93c72e6cdb51ee34b92/src/Storefront/Resources/app/storefront/src/plugin/cookie/cookie-configuration.plugin.js) plugin in a way, so your local storage entries show up in the cookie consent window, yet do not actually set the cookies once accepted.

Personally, I wouldn't bother to go that far, as it might also lead to other issues in the review process. For now I would simply let the entries be set as cookies to get through the review process. Please create an issue on the [issue tracker](https://issues.shopware.com/) explaining the need for local storage settings in the cookie consent window.